# Python Customer Class Objects

Tags: python, class

I just began learning about Python's Class Objects and was asked to complete a beginner level task for a customer class. I've made an attempt on the given requirements, but I'm a little unsure about:

(a) How do I implement a method to check for existing customers

(b) It doesn't explicity state how much discount an existing customer receives so is there a general method I can use to work around this?

(c) Initializing the ClassObject. I think it's something like:

```
c = Customer('Timmy')
c.customer_details()
c.get_discount()
```

Would I need to include the attributes when I'm calling each method?

**Class Customer**

All customers have a unique ID and name. All existing customers are offered discounts. Write the class named Customer to support the following:

(i) Attributes ID and name

(ii) Constructor taking the value for ID and name as arguments

(iii) Appropriate getter/accessor methods for the attributes of this class.

(iv) A method get_discount(self, price) which should be an empty super method.

```
class Customer:
    def __init__(self, customer_name, customer_id, price):
        self.customer_name = customer_name
        self.customer_id = customer_id
        self.price = price

    def customer_details(self, customer_name, customer_id):
        self.customer_name = customer_name
        self.customer_id = customer_id
        
    def get_discount(self, price):
        self.price = price
        pass
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> (a) How do I implement a method to check for existing customers

from what i can see from your code above, the code is just creating a new customer. if you want to check for existing customers, the created customers should be saved to a place first.

> (b) It doesn't explicity state how much discount an existing customer receives so is there a general method I can use to work around this?

sry, i couldnt understand this question. can you provide a clearer explain on what you want to do?

> (c) Would I need to include the attributes when I'm calling each method?

yes. because your `.customer_details()` and `.get_discount()` both require positional arguments to proceed.

Comment: > sry, i couldnt understand this question. can you provide a clearer explain on what > you want to do?

So usually if someone was asked to write a program to check if a customer is a return/new customer. They would be given instructions on how much (%) a return customer should receive if they make a purchase, but it wasn't stated in the instructions. Because we don't know, we can't assume a %, so is there a way to work around this part? Hope that makes a bit more sense.

Comment: so you want to make a flexible method that can enter the discount % when the customer making purchase?

am i correct?